# Problem with calculating touch and gameObject positions on canvas (Screen Space- Camera Render mode)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

all!
I'm working with Unity UI elements. Until recently, my canvas was set to Render mode: Screen space - Overlay. I wrote up some code using touch.position to trigger specific events on my screen: I wanted some objects to appear whenever I would touch an object on my smartphone (or touch within a specific radius of it).

I'm tracking my touch position with `touch.position` and my specific gameObject element positions with a list of positions I create like this:

```
Vector2 thisPosition = new Vector2(child.position.x, child.position.y);
```

When I was working with `Render mode: Screen Space - Overlay`, everything seemed to be working fine in the inspector; but my elements, as they are not part of the UI, weren't displaying.

When I switched to `Render mode: Screen space - Camera` or `World view`, though, my distances started being all over the place.

For example, when touching a button, I would log:

```
Touch position is(341.7, 372.7)
```

While my button's position would log:

```
Button's at(0.0, -1.5)
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Try converting from world space to screen space